# Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_query_var()

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I had a file name: `taxonomy-product_cat-ford.php`

At my home page i had a menu :
`All car | ford | toyota`
Default my homepage alway show all car, i wrote this jquery:

```
$('ul#main-car li a').click(function(){
     $('#content-car').load('<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/content/taxonomy-product_cat-ford.php');
     return false;
});
```

to load `taxonomy-product_cat-ford.php` file which i already query to call products.But when i `click` link item: ford ,it showed me :

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_query_var() in .......

Here is my code:

```
   <?php
      $args = array(
        'post_type' => array('product'), 
        'tax_query' => array(
             'relation' => 'AND',
             array(
                'taxonomy'  => 'product_cat', 
                'field'     => 'slug', 
                'terms'     => array('ford'), 
                'operator'  => 'IN', 
            ),
        ),
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'order' => 'DESC', 
        'orderby' => 'date', 
        'posts_per_page' => 12, 
        'paged' => (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1, 
      );

      // WP_Query
      $eq_query = new WP_Query( $args );
      $offset = 0;
      $eq_total_posts = $eq_query->found_posts - $offset;
      if ($eq_query->have_posts()) :
      $eq_count = $args['paged'] * $args['posts_per_page'] - $args['posts_per_page'];
      ?>
      <?php 
      while ($eq_query->have_posts()): $eq_query->the_post();
      ?>

      <?php woocommerce_product_subcategories(); ?>
      <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); ?>
    <?php 
      endwhile;endif;
      wp_reset_query();
    ?>
```

Comment: It looks like you haven't included anything from wordpress for the file... so none of wordpress' functionality will be available.

Comment: Tks for your help, worked like a charm ^_^.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't included the Wordpress supporting functions into your script, try something along the lines of

```
require_once('wp-config.php');
```

(path from your script to wp-config may vary)